# Visual Studio ClickOnce and Setup & Deployment Projects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have created Excel add in in Visual Studio 2017 in C#. My problem is when I create an installer for it setup.msi using Visual Studio 2017 Installer extension it builds with out any problems and I'm able to install on my local machine but when I start up Excel add in is not on the list. When I'm running the code to test from Visual Studio level it is all working and it adds my add in Excel. What am I missing?